# Practical use of :nth-child() and :nth-of-type() selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

During my journey of self-teaching CSS, I came across the pseudo-selector `:nth-child()` (as well as its related selectors `:nth-last-child()` and `:nth-of-type()`).

I've studied it enough to understand the syntax and operation - but have yet to see any information about **when and why it should be used**.

From what I can tell from Google and Stack Overflow is that it's mainly used to **stylize table rows and lists** - but that seems too simple to be the only operation for a selector that can be so complex.

Am I missing out on something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's uses are only limited by your imagination - I'm not sure anyone could tell you all of them.

Comment: +1 for a well framed question. BTW,You can explore the questions here on SO related to these selectors and you will come to know "Why it is used ? "

Comment: It's completely dependent upon the situation. There's no reason to always use it or not use it.

Comment: well basically you can use this for anything, as @crush said it is only limited by your imagination. I basically use it for recurring styles, alternating rows, navigation...

Comment: Haha, all these comments but no-one can name any other reason than styling tables!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There Are Many Reasons ...

... as others have noted in comments. But you want some non-table or list reasons, so it seems.

**Basic Idea**

With these selectors, you are concerned about *the ordering of **sibling** elements within the html itself* for the selection (this is why they are so commonly used for tables and lists, because `tr`, `td`, and `li` elements are always siblings of one another in there respective place in tables and lists). Secondarily with these selectors you are concerned about being *inclusive or exclusive of **types** of elements* (hence the difference between `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type`; and **one common misconception** is that these pseudo-classes can count by some `.className`, *but they do **not***, they count by html element type: i.e. `<div>`, `<li>`, `<span>`, etc.). In general, they allow for selection of some things when the html is not able to be modified, or structure is variable, but you desire a consistent selector.

**Some Scenarios**

The "why" you might want to target these is what is limitless and I cannot speculate on.

**Example 1**, say you want to style the second to last element in a `div`, no matter what type it is (and dynamic html is being generated, so you don't even know for sure what element it may be), then your only way to access that element is `:nth-last-child(2)`.

**Example 2**, say you want the third `h3` inside a `div`. You have access to change styles but not html (so you cannot put a class on it and it does not have a class or id to target to). However, you know that this `h3` is always the third one of its type in the html, though the number of other elements around it may vary. So `h3:nth-of-type(3)` allows you an ability to target that, an ability you would not have had otherwise.

I could give other scenarios (again, limitless), but if you stick with the concepts noted in "Basic Idea" you can perhaps see why they might be used.

Comment: Example 1 is as good as any, but WHY would you want to do that? About example 2: not having access to the HTML would be a valid reason, but WHEN would that happen?

Comment: I guess this means I can run off for now? I was just typing a much more detailed answer, but due to unforeseen circumstances at home I am going to have to bail out for now :) I will post it when I can.

Comment: @ScottS do you think they can be used as selectors (use css to select dom elements for js) ? I want to explore more into that if possible.

Comment: @BoltClock additional info is always appreciated :)

Comment: @Jonathan: "Why" is impossible to answer other than "because there is some style property one wants to apply to that element under those circumstances." What that would be or why it was desired is impossible to say without an actual case. As to "when" for example 2, if you look around on stack overflow, you will see many times when people say they do not have access to change the html. Whether the client insists it is that way, the designer is swiping the code from another site, or whatever, I just know there are instances it occurs (I've never personally been in that situation).

Comment: @CME64: I'm not quite sure exactly what you are asking, but javascript (especially through the frameworks like [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [MooTools](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/Selectors), etc.) has those capabilities (and more). But even [native javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml) can use them.

Comment: @ScottS thanks a lot, I never knew about the `.querySelector` how could that not be documented in w3s website! if you have more resources about deep things in native js, can you share them please?  I would like to then test the differences in performance between the js selectors and using css selectors.

Comment: @CME64: I really don't have resources to offer. I usually use one of the frameworks. I Googled to get that page, only because I knew such existed (but I've never used it).

Comment: @ScottS thanks anyways, I use frameworks too but I want to build my own sometime and that's why I need a deeper understanding of native js :).

Comment: Trust me to forget to leave an upvote before I went :) My answer mainly contains examples, will be posted in a bit.

Comment: @CME64: Hmm, yeah the Selectors level 3 spec doesn't link to the Selectors API spec for some reason. I know Selectors level 4 does however. Here's the W3C Selectors API spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api

Comment: @BoltClock: Did you decide to let it go, or is a "bit" in your part of the world more like a "terrabit" in mine (with respect to "will be posted in a bit") ;-).

Comment: Haha, it's an old habit of mine :) I'll get to it over the weekend. It's not *that* long an answer.